# The variable x hold the below string data. How can i parse it to use as an object

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

The variable x holds the below string data. How can i parse it to use as an object.

```
 var x = '{"name":"john","age":26,"job":"painter"}{"name":"rahul","age":28,"job":"designer"}{"name":"sachin", "age": 30, "job": "marketer"}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoimport/

Use `mongoimport` to import json data.

```
mongoimport --db test --collection data --file file.json --jsonArray
```

---

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany